# Regular expression to extract dots that are in text

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a simple RE question, I want to extract dots that are in between text, but not the dots that are between decimal numbers like `4454.54`. I need that to separate them from words ..

I created the following RE: `[^\d+(.*?)+\d]`

But it extracts the text that has dots in it!

Comment: That regex doesn't match your description at all. Dots that are neither preceded nor followed by a digit would be `(?<!\d)\.(?!\d)`. Use a regex explainer like https://regex101.com/ to help you along.

Comment: Check it here: https://pythex.org/

Comment: Thanx for the solution, could you propose to me any resource to learn how to built a RE ?

Comment: You mean other than the one I just did? On SO, perhaps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4736/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618/3001761. I'd recommend research.

Comment: You asked about a resource to learn about Regex. Try www.rexegg.com - in my opinion quite a good tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex proposed by *jonrsharpe* fails to match a dot **after** the number,
and I think, it should be matched.

So my proposition is: `\.(?!\d)` - a literal dot, not followed by a digit.

For example source text:

```
Take a positive number. For example 4454.54. Then subtract 4.5 from it.
```

it matches 3 dots, following:

- *number*,
- *4454.54*,
- *it*.

As you expect, both dots serving as decimal points (in *4454.54* and *4.5*) are
**not** matched.